# Is there a way in Jolt, we can use an array of ids and extract values from a separate map to create an array of objects? Please refer this example:

Tags: json, jolt

I would need to create a new array of objects based on the `ids` in the array of input JSON. Because the input is dynamic and can have multiple different `ids`.
The `comment`, `key`, and `type` in the `textFields` will have keys based on those ids.

**Jolt input:**

```json
{
  "textFields": {
    "comment_12345": "Test comment A",
    "comment_67890": "Test comment B",
    "key_12345": "key A",
    "key_67890": "key B",
    "type_12345": "CVC",
    "type_67890": "AVF"
  },
  "access_id": [
    "12345",
    "67890"
  ]
}
```

**Expected JSON output:**

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "comment": "Test comment A",
      "key": "key A",
      "type": "CVC"
    },
    {
      "id": "67890",
      "comment": "Test comment B",
      "key": "key B",
      "type": "AVF"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through `access_id` values and use each value as `id` and get other values from `textFields` with the `access_id` values.

So you can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "access_*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@1": "data[&2].&(3,1)",
            "@(4,textFields.comment_&)": "data[&2].comment",
            "@(4,textFields.key_&)": "data[&2].key",
            "@(4,textFields.type_&)": "data[&2].type"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working. One question: &(3,1) is referring to the "id" from "access_*" where " * " is replaced with "id"?

Comment: @Kaushik Your welcome. Exactly. You say go `3` levels up and get index `1`. If you write `&(3,0)` or `&3` it means full of key that is `access_id`

Answer (score 1):

Yet, you can make your case more dynamic as looping both `textFields` object
and `access_id` array independently through separating by common factors which
come from the values following underscores within the keys of the object versus
components of the array using the method below as the transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "textFields": {
        "*_*": "&(0,2).&(0,1)" // "the piece after underscore"."the piece before underscore"
      },
      "access_*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "@(3,&2[&1]).&(2,1)" // "going 3 levels up the tree by traversing one `:` and two `{`; while using the indexes of the array"."going 2 levels up and grab the 1st replacement of asterisk"   
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the reformed object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]